# Combating Chrome's Flash of Missing Text

Tags: css, google-chrome, webfonts

Chrome will hide text it's waiting for a font for until the font has downloaded or a timeout expires.

On a page where all the fonts are cached I still see a flash of missing text for ~0.25-0.5s.

[image: network]

Site in question is https://history.newtheatre.org.uk/about/, the about section is the best for exploring this issue as there are minimal other assets being loaded in when switching pages.

This issue is not present in Firefox.

Comment: This article provides the whole context and several solutions https://css-tricks.com/fout-foit-foft/